# Partitioning data across hosts in Ansible (access "index" of host in task?)

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I am trying to use Ansible to do some parallel computation. My data is trivially parallelizable, I just need to split the file across my hosts (EC2 instances). Is there a canonical way to do this?

The next best thing would be to have a counter that increments for each host. Assuming I have already split my data into my number of workers, I would like to be able to say within each worker task:

```
- file: src=data/users-{{host_index}}.csv dest=/mnt/users.csv`.
```

Then, each worker can process their copy of `users.csv` with a separate script, that is agnostic to which set of users they have. Is there any way to get this counter index?

I am a beginner to Ansible, so I wonder whether I am overlooking a simple module or idiom, either in Ansible or Jinja. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like I have access to an `ami_launch_index` variable inside of `ec2_facts`. Looking into how to apply that in a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I have access to a variable called [ami_launch_index](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) inside of the `ec2_facts` module that gives me a zero-indexed unique ID to each EC2 instance. Here is the code for copying over files with numerical suffixes to their corresponding EC2 instances:

```
  tasks: 
  - name: Gather ec2 facts
    action: ec2_facts
    register: facts
  - name: Share data to nodes
    copy: src=data/websites-{{facts.ansible_facts.ansible_ec2_ami_launch_index}}.txt dest=/mnt/websites.txt
```

The copy line produces the following for the src values:

```
data/websites-1.txt
data/websites-0.txt
data/websites-2.txt
```

(There is no guarantee that the hosts will iterate in ami_launch_index order)